# Spring MVC @EnableAsync causes error in WildFly 2020.x.x.x

Tags: java, spring, wildfly

I am implementing asynchronous methods in spring mvc with WildFly Server 20.x.x.x but when I want to deploy it an error occurs due to the implementation of the @EnableAsync annotation

**My async configuration:**

```
@Configuration
@EnableAsync
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"xxxx.xxxx.xxxx.xxxx"})
public class WebAsyncConfig extends AsyncConfigurerSupport {
    @Override
    public Executor getAsyncExecutor() {
        return ...;
    }

    @Override
    public AsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler getAsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler() {
        return ...;
    }
}
```

**when the @EnableAsync annotation is declared the error occurs**

```
10:11:41,833 ERROR [org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 49) Context initialization failed: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'apiAreaController' defined in VFS resource ["/D:/AG/IdeaProjects/salesviewer/target/salesviewer/WEB-INF/classes/com/deytecsv/salesviewer/controller/api/ApiAreaController.class"]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'areaService' defined in VFS resource ["/D:/AG/IdeaProjects/salesviewer/target/salesviewer/WEB-INF/classes/com/deytecsv/salesviewer/service/AreaService.class"]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.aop.framework.AopConfigException: Unexpected AOP exception; nested exception is org.springframework.aop.framework.AopConfigException: Unable to instantiate proxy using Objenesis, and regular proxy instantiation via default constructor fails as well; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.deytecsv.salesviewer.service.AreaService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$88c544b6.<init>()
at deployment.salesviewer.war//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:799)
at deployment.salesviewer.war//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:228)
at deployment.salesviewer.war//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1356)
at deployment.salesviewer.war//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1203)
at deployment.salesviewer.war//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:556)
at deployment.salesviewer.war//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:516)
at deployment.salesviewer.war//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324)
at deployment.salesviewer.war//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
at deployment.salesviewer.war//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322)
at deployment.salesviewer.war//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
at deployment.salesviewer.war//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:897)
at deployment.salesviewer.war//org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:879)
at deployment.salesviewer.war//org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:551)
at deployment.salesviewer.war//org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:702)
at deployment.salesviewer.war//org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:578)
at deployment.salesviewer.war//org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:530)
at deployment.salesviewer.war//org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:170)
at javax.servlet.api@2.0.0.Final//javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:180)
at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.3.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.proceed(LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.java:117)
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@22.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.RunAsLifecycleInterceptor.init(RunAsLifecycleInterceptor.java:78)
at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.3.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.proceed(LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.java:103)
at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.3.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedServlet$DefaultInstanceStrategy.start(ManagedServlet.java:305)
at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.3.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedServlet.createServlet(ManagedServlet.java:145)
at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.3.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$2.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:588)
at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.3.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$2.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:559)
at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.3.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:42)
at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.3.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@22.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.java:105)
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@22.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1530)
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@22.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1530)
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@22.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1530)
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@22.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1530)
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@22.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1530)
at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.3.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.start(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:601)
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@22.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.startContext(UndertowDeploymentService.java:97)
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@22.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:78)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1990)
at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)



Caused by: org.springframework.aop.framework.AopConfigException: Unexpected AOP exception; nested exception is org.springframework.aop.framework.AopConfigException: Unable to instantiate proxy using Objenesis, and regular proxy instantiation via default constructor fails as well; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.deytecsv.salesviewer.service.AreaService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$88c544b6.<init>()
    at deployment.salesviewer.war//org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy.getProxy(CglibAopProxy.java:214)
    at deployment.salesviewer.war//org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyFactory.getProxy(ProxyFactory.java:110)
    at deployment.salesviewer.war//org.springframework.aop.framework.AbstractAdvisingBeanPostProcessor.postProcessAfterInitialization(AbstractAdvisingBeanPostProcessor.java:92)
    at deployment.salesviewer.war//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsAfterInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:430)
    at deployment.salesviewer.war//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1798)
    at deployment.salesviewer.war//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:594)
    ... 53 more
Caused by: org.springframework.aop.framework.AopConfigException: Unable to instantiate proxy using Objenesis, and regular proxy instantiation via default constructor fails as well; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.deytecsv.salesviewer.service.AreaService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$88c544b6.<init>()
    at deployment.salesviewer.war//org.springframework.aop.framework.ObjenesisCglibAopProxy.createProxyClassAndInstance(ObjenesisCglibAopProxy.java:81)
    at deployment.salesviewer.war//org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy.getProxy(CglibAopProxy.java:205)
    ... 58 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.deytecsv.salesviewer.service.AreaService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$88c544b6.<init>()
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3349)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.java:2553)
    at deployment.salesviewer.war//org.springframework.aop.framework.ObjenesisCglibAopProxy.createProxyClassAndInstance(ObjenesisCglibAopProxy.java:75)
    ... 59 more
```

**The same application has been deployed in Tomcat, TomEE, Jetty Server and everything works correctly, without problems.**

Answer (score 0):

This looks like an issue with the library Wildfly uses to create proxies of your classes. The constructor for the areaService bean is not compatible. Given the exception message, without seeing the class in question, I would guess it does not have a default constructor defined, which this proxy library may require to work properly. I know this can be an issue with older serialization libraries that need an explicit default constructor to create the object before it can reflectivly set properties.